# Is there any way to avoid showing gray tiles in AGSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis

Added a topograpic layer on a AGISMapView,

```
let layerUrl = "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer"
let url = NSURL(string: layerUrl)!
let mapWithURL = AGSTiledMapServiceLayer.tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL(url) as! AGSTiledMapServiceLayer
self.agsMapView.insertMapLayer(mapWithURL, withName: "AGSMapLayer", atIndex: 0)
```

Issue is whenever we move map to different place it shows Grey tiles, is there any way to avoid this, its ok if it shows tiles in low resolution, but gray tiles not look good.

Let me know if is there any way to avoid this, thanks in advance.

Please check following image for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "gray tiles" you're mentioning are the background color (gray) and grid (lines).

You should look into AGSMapView's properties : backgroundColor, gridLineColor, gridLineWidth, gridSize. For example, setting the gridLineWidth to 0 and the backgroundColor to whiteColor will produce a fully white background.

Comment: thanks for answer, observed same behavior on sample apps provided by ARCGis SDK, its showing white background.